# Reset nesting numeration in ol

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I use the following css to generate nested numeration in `ol`:

```
ol{
    counter-reset: item;
}
ol li{
    display: block;
}
ol li:before{
    content: counters(item, ".")". ";
    counter-increment: item;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

On some level of nesting I want to reset the nesting. How can I achieve it?

For example,

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <ol class="reset">
                            <li>
                                <ol>
                                    <li></li>
                                </ol>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Gives the following:

```
1.
  1.1
     1.1.1
        1.1.1.1
           1.1.1.1.1
```

But I want such structure

```
1.
  1.1
     1.1.1
        1 # reset here
          1.1
```